# Disable "search-ms:displayname=Search Results" in file/folder location

Tags: windows-10, search

Windows has a very annoying feature (for me at least).
For example, you have a folder path like this:

`D:\folder_1\folder_2\folder_3`

when you go to `D:` disk and search for term `folder_3` through **search box** and you will find the folder in search results, any searched item's address (if you COPY & create shortcut to that folder):

`search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results.................`

which is very annoying. It should be just :

`D:\folder_1\folder_2\folder_3`

Is there any way to instruct windows to use plain addresses instead of those? Even created shortcuts of searched folders has similar addresses...

Comment: Can you provides the steps to reproduce this behavior? When I search for and find such a folder, the `Create shortcut` item does not do this. And copying/pasting from the search results copies the file or folder, so I'm not sure where you are seeing the address.

Comment: @DougDeden I mean COPY-ing the address of that folder. Create shortuct of that folder for example.

Comment: Can you provide steps to reproduce this behavior? The only place I'm finding the `search-ms:displayname…` text is in the title bar of the search results window. The `Copy as path`, `Create shortcut`, and `Open folder location` context menu items all result in the correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know, very annoying, what you can do is right click>propeties of a file in that folder and copy the location then paste it in the address bar or run

Comment: As a sidenode: I have tried removing the full registry brach of the URL handler and killing explorer.exe but surprisingly it didn't solve the problem: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\search-ms